# Haskell, "Is Prime" function

Tags: haskell, filter, null, primes, dollar-sign

I am new to Haskell and I couldnt understand the "Null $ filter" thing.

```
isPrime n
  | n < 2 = error "Zu kleine Zahl fuer Primzahltest"
  | otherwise = null $ filter (\k -> n `mod` k == 0) [2.. n-1]
```

Comment: This is equivalent to `null (filter (\k -> n `mod` k == 0) [2.. n-1])`, the `null` is `True` if it is an empty list. So in this case if there are no divisors. The code is however not very efficient.

Comment: Replacing [2..n-1] with [2,,n/2] might be faster.

Comment: I found this solution in a document and i couldn't understand it because I didnt know about the null function, now I got it. Thank you!

Comment: @FrancisKing: you can use `sqrt n` as an upperbound to boost the algorithm, but that is still not the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**`($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-) operator applies the left operand to the right operand. Because it has a low precedence, it is used as a way to "group" expressions. The expression is thus equivalent to:

```
-- null $ filter (\k -> n `mod` k == 0) [2.. n-1]
   null ( filter (\k -> n `mod` k == 0) [2.. n-1] )
```

[**`null :: Foldable f => f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:null) is a function that checks whether a `Foldable` has *no* elements. So for a list, it will return `True` if the list is empty, and `False` otherwise.

The list contains the integers `k` between `2` and `n-1` in ascending order where `` n `mod` k `` is `0`, hence the divisors of `n`. By using `null` we thus check that the number `n` has no divisors, and if that is the case we return `True`; otherwise we return `False`.